# D-branes as the atoms of Calabi-Yau crystals

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, geometry, topological-field-theory, branes

I'm studying the Nishinaka-Yoshida crystal models that encode the generating function of $D4$-$D2$-$D0$ BPS bound states on a Calabi-Yau divisor.

The case of conifold at its singular point is developed in [Statistical model and BPS D4-D2-D0 counting](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2992) and the case $A_{N-1} \times \mathbb{C}$ is discussed in [A note on statistical model for BPS D4-D2-D0 states](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4326).

[image]

The paper that dicuss the conifold case explicitly states that the completely "frozen" crystal (the triangular partition without "triangular atoms" removed) is identifyed as a $D4$-wrapping the conifold. The picture in the above shows the frozen crystal.

A general crystal melting configuration must have atoms removed and should represent a general $D2$-$D0$ bound state "sticked" to the $D4$ brane. The following picture shows an example.

[image]

The authors show that if one identify blue triangles as one unit of $D2$-brane charge and pairs of red and blue triangles as white boxes representing one unit of $D0$ brane charge, then his model is able to compute the desired BPS index.

[image]

I'm unable to see the rationality behind those choices, they seem totally arbitrary to me (beyond the fact that the identifications are needed to reproduce the desired partition function).

**Questions:**

**How can I derive those choices from first principles?**

**Is there any direct relation with the two dimensional Calabi-Yau crystals constructed in [Crystals, instantons and quantum toric geometry](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.3861)?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently found a paper that answer all my questions from first principles and in great detail.

[Two-dimensional crystal melting and D4-D2-D0 on toric Calabi-Yau singularities](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6724)

Further useful references:

[Multiple D4-D2-D0 on the Conifold and Wall-crossing with the Flop](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.6002)

[Vertical D4-D2-D0 bound states on K3 fibrations and modularity](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Ecreutzig/articles/notes_k3_fibrations_final-2.pdf)

[Wall-crossing of D4-branes using flow trees](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1570)